# How can I set Facebook to view by "most recent" rather than "Top Stories"

Tags: facebook

Facebook for Android, Version 8.0.0.26.24

How do I revert back to my preferred method of viewing the most recent stories rather than top stories? The "Cog" icon is no longer where it used to be, and I cannot find where (or if) they re-located a button that has the same function.

Comment: Is v8.x holo? Sorry, I'm on v9.x (beta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto the last tab which has three horizontal lines as its icon. Scroll down a little and you'll see **Most Recent**

Comment: It's under the 'Feeds' heading > Most Recent. One of the worst design choices in an app I've seen in a while.